# Output a currency's sheet from USD to CNY

Tags: java, arrays

I have a task on my education:
"Make a program output a sheet about converting 1,2, ...20 USD to CNY
at the current exchange rate(input from keyboard)"

I'm able to make something like this:

```
public class TaskCurremcy {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter current exchange rate:");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int value = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(convertDollarArray(value)));
}

public static int[] convertDollarArray(int n) {
    int [] currencyArray = new int[21];
    int [] convertedValue = new int[21];
    for (int i = 1; i < currencyArray.length; i++) {
        currencyArray[i] = i;
        convertedValue[i] = currencyArray[i] * n;
    }
    return convertedValue;
  }
}
```

But I have this output if I input '6' from keyboard: `[0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60, 66, 72, 78, 84, 90, 96, 102, 108, 114, 120]`

How to display this in vertical way like a sheet and how to skip '0' and start from '1' position of the array?
Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Use a `for` loop? You've done it once in the conversion method, now do it for the display.

Comment: @Kayaman they way I did it just makes a sheet of same lines..

Comment: Yes, because you did it with `Arrays.toString()` instead of a `for` loop.

Comment: Why are the answers down voted?

Comment: @DeepakAgrawal idk, I can't even vote

Comment: @DeepakAgrawal Low quality answers get downvoted.

Comment: @Kayaman I deleted `Arrays.toString()` and now have vertical display, but it displays something like `[I@4157f54e` any way to display that properly?

Comment: That means you're trying to print the array object instead of the contents of an array index.

Comment: @Kayaman how can I make it vertical and display the contents of an array index simultaneously?

Comment: By iterating the array with a `for` loop, just like you're doing in `convertDollarArray` and printing out the contents with `println`.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks. Any way to skip first '0' index of an array?

Comment: You're doing that already in `convertDollarArray` method. Did you even write that method? Because it seems you've forgotten a lot of things you're doing in that method when you need to write basically the same exact loop and just print the numbers.

Comment: @Kayaman yes, I did write that method. I mean I have output starting from '0', but in the loop in the method I put `for (int i = 1...` why it starts from '0' ?

Comment: Well you never assign `convertedValue[0]` to anything, so the default value of `0`will be there. You don't need to display it of course.

Comment: @Kayaman I assigned it to `6` and now I have this output `[6, 6, 12, 18,` what can I do.. can I hide first index?

Comment: I didn't tell you to assign something to it. Just start your display loop from one like you're doing in the conversion method.

Comment: @Kayaman ok, I got it, made in 'main' It this way:
`for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
            System.out.println(convertDollarArray(value));
        }`
but I get this kind of results `[I@4157f54e`
if I use 'Arrays.toString' I get same lines like `[0, 6, 12, 18, 24,`..
what else can I do to display this `[I@4157f54e` like a value ?

Comment: Your `convertDollarArray()` returns an array. You're supposed to call it once and iterate the array it returns. Not iterate and convert a whole array 21 times.

Comment: @Kayaman I got it sir, I just don't know how to display this `[I@4157f54e` like a value now..

Comment: That's the full `int[]` you're trying to print. You need to index it. Instead of `println(array)` you need `println(array[i])`. Basic array handling.

Comment: @Kayaman oh, that's so simple actually, thank you sir, I appreciate your help very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider adding a utility method for printing your results, and accept the index to skip for as a parameter. The method at the end is an example.

```
public class TaskCurrency {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter current exchange rate:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value = sc.nextInt();
        printVertical(convertDollarArray(value), 0);
    }

    public static int[] convertDollarArray(int n) {
        int[] currencyArray = new int[21];
        int[] convertedValue = new int[21];
        for (int i = 1; i < currencyArray.length; i++) {
            currencyArray[i] = i;
            convertedValue[i] = currencyArray[i] * n;
        }
        return convertedValue;
    }

    // New method to print while skipping
    public static void printVertical(int[] arr, int skipIndex) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            if (i == skipIndex) { // Skip the index you want
            } else
                System.out.println(arr[i]); // Or else print the result in a new array
    }

}
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered bad. They're especially bad when given as answers to homework questions.

Comment: so here actually `if` statement has an empty body, so it does nothing? I mean just skips a specific `i` value and carries on further?
@soufrk

Comment: @ArtyomShakhov Yes, your understanding is absolutely correct, as you have mentioned _how to skip '0' and start from '1' position_ in the question

Comment: @soufrk Thank you sir! You helped me a lot

Comment: @ArtyomShakhov You're welcome. But, the important message here is that you should avoid asking assignment questions on this forum in future, because such questions usually get closed.

Answer (score 0):

You may define your own vertical printing method:

```
public static void printArrayVertically(Object[] array) {
   for (Object obj: array) {
            System.out.println(obj);
   }
}
```

Notice that your class should override toString() method. In this case it's done.

In *main:*

```
printArrayVertically(convertDollarArray(value));
```

Comment: There should be no overriding of `toString()`, you're just using the wrong type of array as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TaskCurrency {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter current exchange rate:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        int[] dollarArray = convertDollarArray(value);
        for (int i = 1; i < dollarArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(dollarArray[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int[] convertDollarArray(int n) {
        int [] currencyArray = new int[21];
        int [] convertedValue = new int[21];
        for (int i = 1; i < currencyArray.length; i++) {
            currencyArray[i] = i;
            convertedValue[i] = currencyArray[i] * n;
        }
        return convertedValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered bad. They're especially bad when given as answers to homework questions.